# Contador de cliques únicos em php com time de 12 horas

Tags: php, contador, click

Olá, estou tentando criar um contador de cliques que grave um log no banco de dados para gravar o IP do visitante para que ao ele clicar no link o contador de cliques só grave se ele clicou após 12 horas do último clique e ele deu no mesmo link.

no banco de dados já tenho a tabela **log_clicks**

[image: no banco de dados já tenho a tabela log_clicks]

Meu código PHP esta desta forma, ele já esta gravando o **uid** que seria o id do link, **ip** e o `time() + 60*60*12` que seria 12 horas a frente para depois fazer o `if(time() > $row_rsClicks['**time'])` que tbm já esta funcionando certinho.

O que preciso agora é saber como fazer para que verifique na tabela **log_clicks** se o **IP** já clicou no link com o **uid** **X** se sim ele então verifica se quando ele clicou já passou de 12 horas se já passou então grave outro log.

Minha ideia é fazer este contador de cliques como deste site https://www.gamestop200.com/ a onde seu clique é somado apenas a pós 12 horas.

```
$colname_rsClicks = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['uid'])) {
  $colname_rsClicks = $_GET['uid'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_connectDB, $connectDB);
$query_rsClicks = sprintf("SELECT * FROM log_clicks WHERE site_uid = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_rsClicks, "int"));
$rsClicks = mysql_query($query_rsClicks, $connectDB) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsClicks = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsClicks);
$totalRows_rsClicks = mysql_num_rows($rsClicks);

$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}


if (isset($_GET["uid"])) {
    if(time() > $row_rsClicks['time']){
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO log_clicks (site_uid, time, ip) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_GET['uid'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString(time() + 60*60*12, "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], "text"));

  mysql_select_db($database_connectDB, $connectDB);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $connectDB) or die(mysql_error());

  $insertGoTo = "/";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}
}

echo $totalRows_rsClicks;
mysql_free_result($rsClicks);
```

Answer (score 0):

Você tem o ID do link, IP do usuário.

Então no primeiro clique do usuário em um link, você aumenta o click para 1, e seta um campo proximo_clique = hora atual + 12.

Quando o usuário clicar no link você verifica, já existe esse IP registrado para esse ID de link? Caso afirmativo, você verifica, a hora atual é maior ou igual ao campo proximo_clique ? Caso afirmativo, você aumenta em um o clique, caso negativo você não aumenta.

Você pode ter uma tabela, com os campos, ID_LINK, IP, CLICKS, NEXT_CLICK...
SELECT * WHERE ID_LINK="link_clicado" AND IP="current_user_ip".....

Comment: já consegui fazer funcionar vlw